# Forge view angle in mobile VR

Tags: virtual-reality, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When starting VR tool on mobile and watching directly ahead, I would like to have the view to show the whole model in the center of the screen. The view should be at a slight angle, so I could see the whole building floor. Currently it is directly ahead, which leaves you with a view where you cannot see the whole model. How could I achieve this?

For example, in this Autodesk example, the model is in the center when you enter VR.

http://viewervr.herokuapp.com/

Current code, with what I am trying to adjust the camera position

```
document.getElementById("toolbar-vrTool").addEventListener("click", function () {
   let _navapi = viewer.navigation;
   let _camera = _navapi.getCamera();

   let xValue = viewer.getCamera().position.x;
   let yValue = viewer.getCamera().position.y;
   let zValue = viewer.getCamera().position.z;

   zValue = zValue * 0.5;
   yValue = (zValue * 0.7071) * -1;

   _camera.position.set(xValue, yValue, zValue);
});
```

Current view

[image: Current view]

View I would like to have

[image: View I would like to have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function named fitToView() which will do exactly what you want. But you need to wait for the geometry to be fully loaded before using it. I also added a call to setHomeViewFrom() in the example below to reset the Home position to the fitToView() position result for later navigation.

```
oViewer.addEventListener (Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, onViewerGeometryLoaded) ;


function onViewerGeometryLoaded () {
    oViewer.removeEventListener (Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, onViewerGeometryLoaded) ;
    oViewer.fitToView (true) ;
    setTimeout (function () { oViewer.autocam.setHomeViewFrom (oViewer.navigation.getCamera ()) ; }, 1000) ;
}
```